# Why does no one in the Hunger Games have to travel to attend the Reaping?

Tags: the-hunger-games

Reading the Hunger Games books and watching the movies, I have noticed that everyone in Panem's districts seems to live in the same general area. Everyone in District 12 knows everyone; there is no mention of people having to travel to a central city in the district in order for the Reaping to be conducted.

This seems strange, considering that the districts are all rather large. Yes, the war nearly a century ago decimated the population, and yes, famine has been a problem. But is it realistic to expect everyone living in a large district to live in the same central area?

Could the population in the districts other than 12 be more spread out, requiring Reaping procedures to be different? Or are all districts like 12, with the entire population apparently living in only one small central area?

Would Reaping procedures have to be more complicated than the books suggest?

Comment: Good question, you will find the answers [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8096/21267) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37535/21267).

Answer (score 5):

Why don't the districts better utilize outside resources? Because they're not allowed to.

Remember, the capital is continuously doing everything they can to oppress the remaining twelve districts. The capital specifically wants the citizens of the twelve districts to have just enough hope to continue to survive and produce goods and entertainment (by way of the Hunger Games) for them.

To this end, each district is surrounded by fences, and the perimeters are patrolled by armed guards sent by, and loyal to the capital. This means that citizens may not venture beyond the district as defined by the Capital, nor may they utilize any additional resources beyond the borders.

There is some additional discussion regarding the breaking of laws, and why people don't do it [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8920/5184).

Regarding the locations of the reapings themselves, these take place within each district. The citizens of each district typically never leave their districts unless they have been chosen for the Hunger Games. The first book is quite clear that the Reaping for District 12 takes place in their own public area.

> At one o’clock, we head for the square. Attendance is mandatory unless you are on death’s door. This evening, officials will come around and check to see if this is the case. If not, you’ll be imprisoned. It’s too bad, really, that they hold the reaping in the square—one of the few places in District 12 that can be pleasant.

It also discusses the fact that the square doesn't have enough room for their own citizens, and that the Reaping is televised

> The space gets tighter, more claustrophobic as people arrive. The square’s quite large, but not enough to hold District 12’s population of about eight thousand. Latecomers are directed to the adjacent streets, where they can watch the event on screens as it’s televised live by the state.

It goes on to confirm that the broadcast is seen all across Panem.

> The mayor looks distressed. Since all of this is being televised, right now District 12 is the laughingstock of Panem, and he knows it.

Answer (score 1):

For District 12 this is true. Essentially District 12 is just a single mine producing coal for the Panem Capitol. No doubt people live stacked together in a small space for better control. And will therefore be able to walk to the location of the Reaping.

But other districts are different. According to The Hunger Games Wiki the agricultural [District 11](http://thehungergames.wikia.com) for example is much larger so will be organised differently.